# Can't assign variable length array size by scanf()

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, scanf

I am trying to get user input using scanf() to get the array size. There are 2 arrays, the scanf() asks for 2 numbers separated by a space. The first array's size can never be assigned but the second one has no issues at all!

This is the code and below is the Environment I'm using

```c
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t numEleArr1 = 0, numEleArr2 = 0;   
    printf("Enter the number of elements in Array-1 and Array-2 separated by a space: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &numEleArr1, &numEleArr2);
    
    int32_t arr1[numEleArr1];
    int32_t arr2[numEleArr2];
}
```

The numEleArr1 will not be assigned to arr1! Why?

Please note I am using an external console to allow user input, but that doesn't affect the program because even without it I am still getting errors!

Sorry, I forgot to circle the variable in question. But you can have a look at the variables at the left side of the below screenshot, `arr1`'s value is unknown `??` but `arr2`'s value is successfully inputted.

[image: debugger screenshot]

Environment:

- Mac OS BigSur (intel)
- VS Code

Edit1:
The full new code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)   // '\n' = ASCII(10) = Line feed or crriage return or New Line
        c = getchar();
}

void swapArrays(int32_t *array1, uint32_t numAr1Ele, int32_t *array2, uint32_t numAr2Ele);
void printArray(int32_t *pArray, uint32_t nElements);



int main(void)
{
    uint32_t numEleArr1 = 0, numEleArr2 = 0;   
    
    for (;;) {      /* loop continually until valid input provided */
        int rtn;    /* return for scanf */
        fputs ("\nEnter the number of elements in Array-1 "
                "and Array-2 separated by a space: ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        
        /* read values, save return, note proper syntax for exact width types */
        rtn = scanf ("%" SCNu32 "%" SCNu32, &numEleArr1, &numEleArr2);
        
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user canceled with ctrl+d (ctrl+z on windows) */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            return 0;
        }
        empty_stdin();      /* empty stdin */
        
        if (rtn != 2)       /* matching failure */
            fputs ("error: invalid uint32_t input.\n", stderr);
        else
            break;          /* good input, break read-loop */
    }
    
    int32_t arr1[numEleArr1];   /* declare VLAs */. // <<<------ This is the problem, The numEleArr1 won't be assigned to this VLA
    int32_t arr2[numEleArr2];  // <<--- This has no issues at all!
    
    /* output array size */
    printf ("arr1[%" PRIu32 "]  arr2[%" PRIu32 "]\n", numEleArr1, numEleArr2);
    fflush(stdout);

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numEleArr1; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Array-1 element's number %u: " ,(i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numEleArr2; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Array-2 element's number %u: " ,(i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);        
    }

    printf("\n\nArray-1 elements before swap are: ");
    printArray(arr1, numEleArr1);

    printf("\nArray-2 elements before swap are: ");
    printArray(arr2, numEleArr2);

    swapArrays(arr1, numEleArr2, arr2, numEleArr2);
    printf("\n\nArrays contents after swapping: ");
    
    printf("\n\nArray-1 elements after swap are: ");
    printArray(arr1, numEleArr1);

    printf("\nArray-2 elements after swap are: ");
    printArray(arr2, numEleArr2);
    
    
    printf("\n\nPress any key to exit program . . . ");
    while(getchar() == 0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}




void printArray(int32_t *pArray, uint32_t nElements)
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        printf("%10d", pArray[i]);
    }
}




void swapArrays(int32_t *array1, uint32_t numAr1Ele, int32_t *array2, uint32_t numAr2Ele)
{
    //In case one of the arrays has lesser elements than the other, the iteration must be over the least elements to prevent segfaults.
    uint32_t len = numAr1Ele < numAr2Ele ? numAr1Ele : numAr2Ele;   //len = whichever lower in elements count
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int32_t temp = array1[i];
        array1[i] = array2[i];
        array2[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

The output will be as follows:

```
Enter the number of elements in Array-1 and Array-2 separated by a space: 3 4
arr1[3]  arr2[4]
Enter the Array-1 element's number 1: 1

Enter the Array-1 element's number 2: 2

Enter the Array-1 element's number 3: 3


Enter the Array-2 element's number 1: 9

Enter the Array-2 element's number 2: 8

Enter the Array-2 element's number 3: 7

Enter the Array-2 element's number 4: 6


Array-1 elements before swap are:          1         2         3
Array-2 elements before swap are:          9         8         7         6

Arrays contents after swapping: 

Array-1 elements after swap are:          9         8         7
Array-2 elements after swap are:          1         2         3         1

Press any key to exit program . . .
```

Here is a screenshot of the debugger:
[A screenshot of the debugger:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZfln.png)

Comment: Could be a debugger issue.  Does the program work otherwise?

Comment: Could you tell which compiler do you use? And btw, using %d for an unsigned integer could be a bad practice.

Comment: @dbush No, it doesn't!  ...

Comment: @thetaprime clang and lldb debugger.. what to use for an unsigned integer instead?

Comment: If your program does not work, you might have other errors, as some comments and answers suggest. Anyway, I think this is just a debugger quirk. What is your optimization level? The pointer to `arr1` might not be fetched into a visible register or variable at the current location, even if enough space is already allocated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of subtle issues, not the least of which is failing to use the proper exact-width format specifiers for both `scanf()` and `printf()` (provided in `inttypes.h`). Further, you are attempting to read *unsigned* values with the *signed* `%d` conversion specifier.

Additionally, you have no way of knowing whether your input succeeded or failed because you fail to ***check the return*** from `scanf()`. (you cannot use ANY input function correctly unless you ***check the return***)

[C11 Standard - 7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1) provides proper macros for both input and output of exact-width types. When using `scanf()` the proper conversion specifier is `SCN{fmt}{type}` where `fmt` is one of `d` (decimal), `x` (hexadecimal), `o` (octal), `u` (unsigned) and `i` (integer). `type` is one of `N`, `FASTN`, `LEASTN`, `PTR`, `MAX`, where `N` corresponds to the number of bits in the argument. The format specifiers for `printf()` are similar using `PRI`. (note, the macros must not be within double-quotes to expand properly)

Putting that together with an input routine that requires the user enter two valie `uint32_t` values or cancel the input with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows). If the user enters an invalid `uint32_t` value like `"foo"`, you must empty `stdin` before your next attempt or the same characters will remain in `stdin` unread resulting in the exact same failure (a simple function is used for that purpose below)

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t numEleArr1 = 0, numEleArr2 = 0;   
    
    for (;;) {      /* loop continually until valid input provided */
        int rtn;    /* return for scanf */
        fputs ("\nEnter the number of elements in Array-1 "
                "and Array-2 separated by a space: ", stdout);
        
        /* read values, save return, note proper syntax for exact width types */
        rtn = scanf ("%" SCNu32 "%" SCNu32, &numEleArr1, &numEleArr2);
        
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user canceled with ctrl+d (ctrl+z on windows) */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            return 0;
        }
        empty_stdin();      /* empty stdin */
        
        if (rtn != 2)       /* matching failure */
            fputs ("error: invalid uint32_t input.\n", stderr);
        else
            break;          /* good input, break read-loop */
    }
    
    int32_t arr1[numEleArr1];   /* declare VLAs */
    int32_t arr2[numEleArr2];
    
    /* output array size */
    printf ("arr1[%" PRIu32 "]  arr2[%" PRIu32 "]\n", numEleArr1, numEleArr2);
    
    (void)arr1, (void)arr2;     /* cast to (void) to avoid -Wunused warning */
}
```

The values for `numEleArr1` and `numEleArr2` are output showing the results. The casts to `(void)` simply avoid the compiler warnings for `arr1` and `arr2` being unused.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/uin32t_scn_pri

Enter the number of elements in Array-1 and Array-2 separated by a space: foo bar
error: invalid uint32_t input.

Enter the number of elements in Array-1 and Array-2 separated by a space: 21 97
arr1[21]  arr2[97]
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Why you did not use dynamically allocated array like `int32_t* arr1 = malloc(numEleArr1*sizeof(int32_t));` because it will allocate in **run time**  instead of `int32_t arr1[numEleArr1];` which need to know numEleArr1 value in **compile time**

Comment: Hm, this does not answer the core question of the OP: The debugger shows that the values "3" and "4" were entered, but only `arr2` is shown with a size. Why is `arr1` not shown with a size?

Comment: @IbramReda because the question with `int32_t arr1[numEleArr1];` declares VLAs (Variable Length Arrays), which do not need allocation. (that's the purpose for VLAs), but note, compiler support for VLAs are optional beginning with C11. (though most continue to support them)

Comment: @thebusybee I'm not sure what is shown in the picture, I cannot even make the text out. (not even with my trusty magnifying glass)

Comment: The problem is not very clear, yes, and the OP forgot to circle the important part. It's in the "VARIABLES" view, the "locals". It took me some minutes to see the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear now. Please check it out.

Comment: @ENG_MOH If your picture shows there is a problem with `arr1`, then the cause of that problem is not apparent from the code you posted. Meaning, there is no reason that `arr1` would be treated any differently from `arr2` in what you show. The only plausible reason would be your source contains a non-visible control character such as a copy/paste from windows UTF-16 or unicode. (Mac may handle that fine, I don't know, but doubt the compiler would). Take a look at a hex dump (e.g. `hexdump -Cv yourfile.c`) and confirm.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No matter how I try, I still have the same issue, The ```arr1```'s size is shown as ```??``` although the console prints ```arr1[3]  arr2[4]``` in the debugger. I have attached the full code. I have no idea what the problem is!

Comment: My first thought is to implement the input validations (saving and checking the `scanf()` return) so you can validate the number passed as `numEleArr1` was indeed validly received as input. I don't see anything else it can be. If you want to edit your question and ADD your new code at the end, I'm happy to compile and run it and see if there is anything else I'm missing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin .. I edited the question. Please find the full code attached there. It is really weird I have never encountered such an issue before! Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, Aside from the erroneous `'.'` on line 42 after `/* declare VLAs */ .` code compiles and runs without error producing the output you show. Both `numEleArr1` and `numEleArr2` are properly filled and both VLA are properly initialized. When you say `"This is the problem, The numEleArr1 won't be assigned to this VLA"` -- of course not, you are not "assigning" `numEleArr1` to `arr1`, you are using it to specify the number of elements in the VLA. (I think that is what you meant).  The code does exactly what you are telling it to do. Do you see something different?